# TCP client using a specific interface while connecting to a webserver

Tags: sockets, tcp, interface, client, bind

I am trying to connect over Linux. My device is connected to two LANs (say eth0 and eth1) with different networks.

Both networks are connected to internet. I want my client program to be able to use eth1 even though my eth0 is the default interface.

There is an option setsockopt (SO_BINDTODEVICE) to bind to a specific interface but requires root priviledges which is not possible.

Binding to IP address of eth1 is not helping either. Please suggest is there any other way through socket APIs to link the connection with the interface. i.e. my client program will always usse eth1 source IP and interface to connect to the internet whereas all other programs will continue to use eth0 as ususal.

I investigated and appears changes in routing table can help in this but trying to avoid being risky to make system unstable as that is applied to every other programs too.

Thanks in advance.
Kris

Comment: For an IP-based (TCP or UDP) socket, passing the interface's local IP address to `bind()` prior to calling `connect()` is the correct and preferred way to go. However, using `SO_BINDTODEVICE` with the interface's device name should work as well. If neither are working, then you are doing something wrong. Please show your actual code.

Comment: Well there's certainly no other way to do it. You'll have to tell us exactly what 'not helping' actually means.